# Is there anyway to prepend a jar to the unmanagedClasspath in sbt

Tags: android, scala, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

I am using the `android-sbt-plugin` with the sbt, and I would like to add an unmanaged jar to the test classpath. The reason being android.jar contains stub functions for the org.json libraries and results in exceptions being thrown for unit tests. This is what I am doing

```
    unmanagedClasspath in Test <+= (baseDirectory) map { base =>
    Attributed.blank(base/"test-libs"/"json.jar")
    }
```

Because of the order of the jars this file is ignored during when i run the test command within the sbt. If I type the command the order clearly shows the android.jar as the first jar

> show test:unmanaged-classpath
>       [info] ArrayBuffer(Attributed(/home/rohit/Projects/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android- 17/android.jar), Attributed(/home/rohit/Projects/barfrendz/trunk/src/buzze/test-libs/json.jar))

If I create a lib folder and let sbt pick up the json jar the order is reversed the tests now run, but I can no longer create an android package due to conflicts with the org.json namespace in android.jar. Here is the exception

```
[error] (Buzze/android:proguard) java.io.IOException: Can't read [/home/rohit/Projects/barfrendz/trunk/src/buzze/lib/json.jar(;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,!**/R.class,!**/R$*.class,!**/TR.class,!**/TR$.class,!**/library.properties)] (Can't process class [org/json/CDL.class] (Unsupported version number [51.0] for class format))
```

Is there anyway I can change the order of the jars in the classpath for the unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<+=`, use `<<=`, get `unmanagedClasspath` itself as a dependency, and then modify it as desired. The [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Best-Practices.html) has such an example with `resolvers`:

```
resolvers <<= resolvers {rs =>
  val localMaven = "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
  localMaven +: rs
}
```

This way, `localMaven` ends up first in `resolvers`.

According to the [API docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/api/#sbt.Keys%24), the `unmanagedClasspath` is a `Task` of type `Classpath`. Note that when you use that syntax, you are changing the `Classpath`, not the `Task`.

The API doc for the classpath is [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/api/#sbt.Keys%24) -- it's a `type`, and it points to `Seq[Attributed[File]]`, so you can manipulate it with any `Seq` command. I tried out the snippet here and it works:

```
$ cat build.sbt
unmanagedClasspath in Test <<= (unmanagedClasspath in Test, baseDirectory) map { (uc, base) =>
    Attributed.blank(base/"test-libs"/"json.jar") +: uc
}

Daniel@DANIEL-PC /c/scala/Programas/sbtTest
$ sbt
[info] Set current project to default-60c6f9 (in build file:/C:/scala/Programas/sbtTest/)
> show test:unmanaged-classpath
[info] ArrayBuffer(Attributed(C:\scala\Programas\sbtTest\test-libs\json.jar))
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 30/08/2013 13:32:42
>
```

Comment: This is what i want however the Task[] class does not have the +: operator. If I find something equivalent I will post it here

Comment: @Rohit The advice I gave does work. I've added more information to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe overriding the unmanagedJars instead of the unmanagedClasspath would allow you to do this:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html