# Custom resourceDirectory for Revolver/Spray

Tags: sbt, spray, sbt-revolver

I have a Spray application with a basic front end component with source in src/main/frontend and the deployed version (compiled sass, minification etc.) in Spray's default resources location src/main/resources. I would like to change the resource directory to src/main/frontend for Revolver's `re-start` task only, in order to see changes quicker when developing.

I have tried adding the setting

```
resourceDirectory in Revolver.reStart <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src" / "main" / "frontend")
```

but it doesn't seem to have an effect. I guess because `resourceDirectory` is a setting in the `Compile` scope and not one in Revolver itself. In the SBT console:

```
> reStart:resourceDirectory
[info] /Users/cartew01/workspace/applaudio-spray/src/main/frontend
> compile:resourceDirectory
[info] /Users/cartew01/workspace/applaudio-spray/src/main/resources
```

Does anyone know how I can change this for the `re-start` task but not for any others? Possibly by creating a custom task that calls re-start with the additional setting?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should add your another resource directory to the fullClasspath in reStart, for instance `(fullClasspath in Revolver.reStart) += (WebKeys.public in Assets in web).value`, or in your case `fullClasspath in Revolver.reStart += baseDirectory(_ / "src" / "main" / "frontend")` - actually, getFromResourceDirectory and getFromResource will serve contents from the classpath.

Comment: actually, to better understand it, i suggest running `inspect reStart` - it depends on `compile:products`, which in turn depends on `compile:copyResources`, which in turn depends on `compile:resourceDirectories`. So, reStart will use whatever is produced by compiler, i.e. resources copied from somewhere. The solution above seems a bit easier.

Comment: Brilliant solution to the problem. Thanks a lot. However, I'm now stuck with something a lot more trivial. I've added `fullClasspath in Revolver.reStart += baseDirectory(_ / "src" / "main" / "frontend").value` to the build as suggested and it works but I'd like this directory to appear at the start of the classpath. How do I append a file to an SBT classpath? Thanks again.

Comment: Found the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525478/is-there-anyway-to-prepend-a-jar-to-the-unmanagedclasspath-in-sbt. You can map classpaths: `fullClasspath in Revolver.reStart <<= (fullClasspath in Revolver.reStart, baseDirectory) map { (classpath, base) => Attributed.blank(base/"src"/"main"/"frontend") +: classpath }` Thanks abatyuk.

Comment: As noone else chimed in, put the solution above as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your another resource directory to the `fullClasspath` in reStart, for instance `(fullClasspath in Revolver.reStart) += (WebKeys.public in Assets in web).value`, or in your case `fullClasspath in Revolver.reStart += baseDirectory(_ / "src" / "main" / "frontend")` - actually, `getFromResourceDirectory` and `getFromResource` will serve contents from the class path.

to better understand it, i suggest running `inspect reStart` - it depends on `compile:products`, which in turn depends on `compile:copyResources`, which in turn depends on `compile:resourceDirectories`. So, reStart will use whatever is produced by compiler, i.e. resources copied from somewhere. The solution above seems a bit easier